# Switching to developer mod doesn't help much

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, compile

When I switch my Magento 2 to developer mode it doesn't do much for me. I practically don't see any benefit from it. When I change something in my plugin it has no effect on the front end. If I change something in JS or HTML it doesn't change it in real time.
Only games I call full cleanup commands:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php bin/magento cache:flush`

That's just to see the changes. And these commands take quite a long time about 5 min to load which drives me crazy.

Comment: As documentation, this mode is intended for development. I think is very helpful that shows errors on the frontend, enables automatic code compilation and enables enhanced debugging

Answer (score 1):

You can always test your code by making changes in your file present in  **pub/static/module-name/filename** and then if your code is working fine in the static js file, copy that code and paste that in your module's js file.

Ps:- If you run the commands without adding the updated code in your module's js you will lose that recently added code in the static file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the developer mode on this page.
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/application-modes.html

You have to run these commands when you change the static files like js, css, or less file.
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

You can change the static files(magento root directory/pub/static/frontend/your theme/...) directly if you want to test the codes.
But you have to update the files again in the app directory after you tested it.

I want this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

it happens most of the time, so please use below command and you will see your changes for sure.
got the you magento installation root directory and run below commad

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static
```

after it refresh your page with (ctrl+f5) command. if sill you do not see your changes then please run

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static
```

I hope it will resolve your issues. please like if it is useful.